# Is there a way to define a constant at build time in Go?

Tags: go, constants, build-time

I have a program in Go that I want to compile in a bunch of binaries, each having a `const` value defined differently. More clearly, I have something like that:

```
const wordLen = 6
type knowledge [wordLen]byte
```

Here, `wordLen` is associated with the value 6, but I want to have different binaries, with values ranging from 5 to 10. I could make it a variable, and then use a slice rather than an array, but that would have a huge performance impact on my soft (yes, I tried).

I would love to have some build tag on `go build` argument to indicate what the value of `wordLen` is for a given binary. So, what is the (as idiomatic as possible) way to do this ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using [Build Constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints).

You can supply a list of these constraints to `go build` using the `-tags` flag.

Example:

#### main.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

#### foo.go

```
// +build foo

package main

const f = "defined in foo.go"
```

#### bar.go

```
// +build bar

package main

const f = "defined in bar.go"
```

Compiling the code with different tags will give different results:

```sh
$ go build -tags foo
$ ./main
defined in foo.go
$ go build -tags bar
$ ./main
defined in bar.go
```

Comment: and what if I just run `go build`? Will the build end with an error complaining about undefined symbol `f`? How can I provide a kind of defaults to use when neither `-tags bar`, nor `-tags foo` is specified?

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't solve your exact problem but it may solve others so I add for completeness that you can use the `-ldflags` option of the go compiler:

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.wordLen=6"
```

Its however has two downsides:

- Only works for strings
- Only works on vars

Comment: Those are huge downsides since I need to use a numeric constant ;) However, this is a very useful functionality in some contexts.